# How to parse XBRL string (not a xml file) with XBRLParser

Tags: python, api, request, xbrl

I have a string returned from a get request which contains XBRL content, How may I parse it with XBRPARSER?
Here is the code:

```
from xbrl import XBRLParser
import base64
decoded = base64.decodebytes(data[0].text.encode()) ---> #decoded has the XBRL content
# data = decoded.find('xbrl')
# dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(decoded)  # or xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
# pretty_xml_as_string = dom.toprettyxml()

# print(pretty_xml_as_string)
xbrl_parser = XBRLParser()
xbrl = xbrl_parser.parse(decoded) #---> File "/Users/~/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xbrl/xbrl.py", line 64, in parse
                                       #file_handler = open(file_handle)
```

I put DOM to show that it has a `parseString` which is I need but for `XBRLParser`

Answer (score 0):

After working on xbrl.py (the source of xbrl library) I came up with this solution:

In parse function of xbrl.py, I commented the line which opens the xml file and reads it then passes it into XBRLPreprocessedFile function. Now it directly passes the parse parameter to XBRLPreprocessedFile without opening it. In XBRLPreprocessedFile function I changed the line `xbrl_string = self.fh.read()` to `xbrl_string = self.fh` since I send a string not a file.

In my code I create `Custome` class as it is created in xbrl.py and pass `decoded.decode('utf-8)` to parse.

My Code:

```
class Custom(object):

    def __init__(self):
        return None

    def __call__(self):
        return self.__dict__.items()

from xbrl import XBRLParser
import base64
decoded = base64.decodebytes(data[0].text.encode())
xbrl_parser = XBRLParser()
xbrl = xbrl_parser.parse(decoded.decode("utf-8"))
# *** here I find all the tags
custom_obj = Custom()
custom_data = xbrl.find_all(re.compile('^((?!(us-gaap|dei|xbrll|xbrldi)).)*:\s*',
                                       re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE))
```

parse function in xbrl.py:

```
def parse(self, file_handle):
    """
    parse is the main entry point for an XBRLParser. It takes a file
    handle. "*** which now takes a string ***"
    """

    xbrl_obj = XBRL()

    # if no file handle was given create our own
    """if not hasattr(file_handle, 'read'):
        file_handler = open(file_handle)
    else:
        file_handler = file_handle"""

    # Store the headers
    xbrl_file = XBRLPreprocessedFile(file_handle)

    xbrl = soup_maker(xbrl_file.fh)
    # file_handler.close()
    xbrl_base = xbrl.find(name=re.compile("xbrl*:*"))

    if xbrl.find('xbrl') is None and xbrl_base is None:
        raise XBRLParserException('The xbrl file is empty!')

    # lookahead to see if we need a custom leading element
    lookahead = xbrl.find(name=re.compile("context",
                          re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)).name
    if ":" in lookahead:
        self.xbrl_base = lookahead.split(":")[0] + ":"
    else:
        self.xbrl_base = ""

    return xbrl
```

change in XBRLPreprocessedFile function in xbrl.py:

```
xbrl_string = self.fh.read() --> xbrl_string = self.fh
```